# g++ not compiling in debug information

Tags: c++, debug-symbols

I have a small .cpp program that compiles and runs and I want to add debugging information to it, so I compile like this:

```
g++ -g a.cpp
```

Then if I check for debug information with the following command:

```
# objdump -g a.out
a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64
objdump: a.out: no recognized debugging information
```

What am I doing wrong?  I expected debug information to be found.

Version information:

```
Linux xxx 2.6.18-308.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jan 27 17:17:51 EST 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
GNU objdump 2.17.50.0.6-20.el5 20061020
```

Comment: GDB works? Do you run a strip command? the man says : -g => Only certain types of debugging information have been implemented

Comment: I've only run the g++ and objdump command listed in the question.  I don't know enough gdb to determine if it is finding debug symbols or not.

Comment: Would you please paste the version of your gcc and your objdump. Would be better if you can tell us your os.

Comment: just do a gdb a.out, if it have the debug symbols it will start fine, if not it will tell you that the symbols cannot be found.
Check with objdump --syms to see if it was stripped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, `objdump -g` is not the most reliable way to check for debug output of gcc. Try `objdump -W`.

Comment: Yes, for whatever reason, objdump -W works as expected where objdump -g doesn't do anything.